# Question about a simple derivative

Tags: derivatives

Let's say we have $y = 10^2$

How much does $y$ increase when $x$ increases by $1$ unit?

We have the form $y=x^2$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x \ldots$ here $x=10$, so why isn't the answer $2(10)=20$?

By simple evaluation the answer is $(11^2)-(10^2)=21$

But thinking about it from the perspective of using the general form of the derivative of $y=x^2$, we could answer it by computing $2(10.5)=21$

Finally, my question is:
What is the reasoning behind the $x$ in "$2x$" being $10.5$?

Comment: $y=100$ is a constant function and doesn't change with time. The answer should be $0$.

Comment: "*when $x$ increases by $1$ unit*"  What is $x$?  $x$ does not appear in the problem statement.  There is no $x$ in the stated equation of $y=10^2$.  This might just as well be $y=10^2 + 0\cdot x$.  Who is to say that $x$ should have been the base of the exponent rather than the exponent itself or something else entirely...

Comment: Now... "*Given that $y=x^2$, considering what happens when $x=10$ and looking at how much $y$ would increase if $x$ were increased by $1$*"... it is a fluke that plugging in $10.5$ to your derivative equation worked.  If this were not $x^2$ and were instead $x^3$ or otherwise it would not have worked.  As for why the derivative is useless here, that's because the derivative looks at the *instantaneous rate of change* as opposed to how much it actually changes over a specific time interval.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that at $x=10, \frac {dy}{dx}=20$, it means that the gradient at the point $(10,100)=20$.

But, being a parabola, the gradient increases as $x$ increases, so that by the time $x=11$, the gradient at $(11,121)$ is $22$.

The gradient of the straight line joining the two points is $21$. Your simple evaluation is actually calculating that gradient, not the gradient at $x=10$.

It just happens to be the case that for this parabola, the point at $x=10.5$ is the midway point, or average, between $x=10$ and $x=11$ and that the gradient at that point is the average gradient between the two other points.

Answer (score 0):

Derivatives are based on infinitesimal changes.  However, you can also formulate those with non-infinitesimal changes.

$$y' = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

We normally do $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}$ on this, but there's no reason you have to.  You can actually set $h$ to whatever you want and it still works.  So, we can find the "full-unit derivative" (where $h = 1$) as follows:

$$f(x) = x^2 \\
f'(x) = \frac{(x + h)^2 - (x)^2}{h} \\
f'(x) = \frac{x^2 + 2xh + h^2 - x^2}{h} \\
f'(x) = \frac{2xh + h^2}{h} \\
f'(x) = 2x + h
$$

So, when $h = 1$, then $f'(x) = 2x +1$.  So, at $x = 10$ the amount that $y$ changes for $1$ unit of $x$ is $2x +1 = 2(10) + 1 = 21$.

Technically, this is called a "difference" equation instead of a "full-unit derivative", but, you know, technicalities.